# vb.net code for operate menu items totaly through keyboard

Tags: vb.net

i am sending a quetion ,how to operate menu items through keyboard....plz give the code for problem....

Comment: Please clarify your question, post some code and explain your question clearly. Read this for some hints: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

For simply adding keyboard shortcut functionality to menu controls, [here's a simple tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets4p4.html) that looks promising.

Comment: please give anotner answer actually i know this mthod but i want operate menu items totaly through keyboard..

Comment: @sandeep: why don't you tell us what you tried and what is not working? Maybe post some of your code? That way we won't have to guess what _isn't_ the answer.

Comment: @sandeep: Define "operate menu items totally through keyboard."  Assigning keyboard shortcuts to menu items allows the user to access them with the keyboard.